# How do i find root url in php similar to server.mappath in .net

Tags: php

i have a page where i need to pass multiple arguments via the url 
i need to get the relative root path of the public_html folder .

I tried some of the functions

```
$path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
echo __FILE__;
$docRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

echo "<br>";
$thisFile = str_replace('\\', '/', __FILE__);
$webRoot  = str_replace(array($docRoot, 'library/config.php'), '', $thisFile);

$srvRoot  = str_replace('library/config.php', '', $thisFile);
echo $docRoot."<br>".$webRoot."<br>".$srvRoot;
$p=getcwd();
echo  "<br>".dirname ( $p );
$my_folder = dirname( realpath( __FILE__ ) ) ;
echo "<br>".$my_folder;
echo "<br>".basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], '.php');
```

i get the path as "/home/elitenua/public_html/gallitest/index.php"

i want the path as "/gallitest/index.php"

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$basedir = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

Thats what you are searching for.